# Bitcoin sent to invalid address

Tags: transactions, address

In this [transaction](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/e8b406091959700dbffcff30a60b190133721e5c39e89bb5fe23c5a554ab05ea), some bitcoins are sent to bc1qp6k6tux6g3gr3sxw94g9tx4l0cjtu2pt65r6xp which appears to not be a valid bitcoin address. What is bc1qp6k6tux6g3gr3sxw94g9tx4l0cjtu2pt65r6xp  ? [image]

Answer (score 1):

That address is a bech32 encoded address, which is a new style of address used on the Bitcoin network, that starts with `bc1...`.

It seems that the Blockchain.info explorer has simply not been updated to properly interpret and present this newer address type. The addresses you listed are perfectly valid.

Comment: They updated to decode them at least.